# Quadratic inequality where $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, inequality, quadratics, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

If $x$ belongs to the set of real numbers, show that $\dfrac x{x^2 - 5x +9}$ always lies in the interval $[\dfrac{-1}{11}, 1]$?

I tried to solve the problem using wavy curve method i.e by plotting the roots of the equation. We see that the denominator has a discriminant less than zero and hence it can be treated as a positive real number. When we treat the denominator as positive number and equate it to 0, we get x=0.
I don't know what mistake I am making in my approach to the question?

The wavy curve method : https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2chw.jpg

Comment: Your mistake is you are not doing anything to address the question.  Why are you equating "it" (the expression?  Then denominator?) to zero.  How is that going to tell you the range of values the expression may be?

Comment: @fleablood I am not sure if you are aware of wavy curve method, no offence meant. I'd have posted a picture from my textbook but I Am quite new to using stack exchange and I could not upload it, probably due to some "trust" issue.

Comment: @fleablood if you dont mind, could you please have a look at the wavy curve method.

Comment: The wavy curve will tell you on which intervals $f(x) < 0$ and $f(x) > 0$. It does not tell you anything about the range of $f(x)$. As there is only one root $x=0$, this splits the reals int in $(-\infty, 0)$ and $(0, \infty)$ If $x < 0$ then $f(x) < 0$ and if $x > 0$ then $f(x) > 0$.  The wavy curve method tells you that much.  Unfortunately that isn't what we want to know.  The wavy curve will not help us with what we want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a mistake in your solution. I think your solution is right:

Let $$\frac{x}{x^2-5x+9}=y.$$
Hence, the equation
$$yx^2-(5y+1)x+9y=0$$ has real roots.

For $y=0$ we get $x=0$.

But, for $y\neq0$ we need 
$$(5y+1)^2-36y^2\geq0,$$ which gives
$$-\frac{1}{11}\leq y\leq1.$$

Also, we can use the following idea.

For $x>0$ by AM-GM we obtain:
$$\frac{x}{x^2-5x+9}=\frac{1}{x+\frac{9}{x}-5}\leq\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x\cdot\frac{9}{x}}-5}=1.$$
For $x<0$ by AM-GM again  we obtain:
$$\frac{x}{x^2-5x+9}=\frac{1}{x+\frac{9}{x}-5}\geq\frac{1}{-2\sqrt{(-x)\left(-\frac{9}{x}\right)}-5}=-\frac{1}{11}.$$
For $x=0$ we get a value $0$ and since $f(x)=\frac{x}{x^2-5x+9}$ is a continuous function, we are done.

Comment: Sir, if you could point out the mistake in my approach where I used the wavy curve method.

Comment: We see that the denominator has a discriminant less than zero and hence it can be treated as a positive real number. When we treat the denominator as positive number and equate it to 0, we get x=0. I don't know what mistake I am making in my approach to the question?

Comment: @Ranjeet Mishra I don't see a mistake in your solution. I think your solution is right. I added something. See now.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the method of intervals (wavy curve method) is used to solve an inequality. The solution of the inequality is indeed:
$$\dfrac x{x^2 - 5x +9}>0 \ \ (<0) \Rightarrow x>0 \ \ (x<0).$$
However, the problem is asking to show the range:
$$-\frac1{11}\le \dfrac x{x^2 - 5x +9}\le 1.$$
You can find the minimum and maximum values of the function: $f(x)=\dfrac x{x^2 - 5x +9}$ by using derivative:
$$\begin{align}f'(x)&=\frac{x^2-5x+9-x(2x-5)}{(x^2-5x+9)^2}=\frac{9-x^2}{(x^2-5x+9)^2}=0 \Rightarrow x=\pm3;\\
f''(-3)&=\frac{2}{363}>0 \Rightarrow f(-3)=-\frac{1}{11} \ (min);\\
f''(3)&=-\frac{2}{3}<0 \Rightarrow f(3)=1 \ (max). \end{align}$$